# Creating a zip archive with Unicode filenames using Go's archive/zip

Tags: string, go, unicode, zip

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var (
        Path = os.Args[1]
        Name = os.Args[2]
    )

    File, _ := os.Create(Name)
    PS := strings.Split(Path, "\\")
    PathName := strings.Join(PS[:len(PS)-1], "\\")
    os.Chdir(PathName)
    Path = PS[len(PS)-1]
    defer File.Close()
    Zip := zip.NewWriter(File)
    defer Zip.Close()
    walk := func(Path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        Src, _ := os.Open(Path)
        defer Src.Close()
        fmt.Println(Path)
        FileName, _ := Zip.Create(Path)
        io.Copy(FileName, Src)
        Zip.Flush()
        return nil
    }
    if err := filepath.Walk(Path, walk); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

This mydir path :

```
-----root
    |---2015-05(dir)
         |---中文.go
    |---package(dir)
    |---你好.go
```

When I use this code directory, Chinese will be garbled. Who can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that by default in zip entry names only the ASCII characters are allowed by the [Zip specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), more specifically: (Source: [APPENDIX D](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT))

> **APPENDIX D.1** The ZIP format has historically supported only the original IBM PC character 
>   encoding set, commonly referred to as IBM Code Page 437.  This limits storing 
>   file name characters to only those within the original MS-DOS range of values 
>   and does not properly support file names in other character encodings, or 
>   languages. To address this limitation, this specification will support the 
>   following change.

Later support for Unicode names has been added. This can be marked with a special bit referred to as `general purpose bit 11`, also called `Language encoding flag (EFS)`:

> **Section 4.4.4** - General purpose bit flag - Bit 11 - Language encoding flag (EFS).  If this bit is set, the filename and comment fields for this file MUST be encoded using UTF-8.
>
> **APPENDIX D.2** If general purpose bit 11 is unset, the file name and comment should conform 
>   to the original ZIP character encoding.  If general purpose bit 11 is set, the 
>   filename and comment must support The Unicode Standard, Version 4.1.0 or 
>   greater using the character encoding form defined by the UTF-8 storage 
>   specification.  The Unicode Standard is published by the The Unicode
>   Consortium (www.unicode.org).  UTF-8 encoded data stored within ZIP files 
>   is expected to not include a byte order mark (BOM).

The `general purpose bit flag` is present and supported by Go: it is the `Flags` field of the [`FileHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader) struct. Unfortunately Go doesn't have methods to set this bit, and by default it is 0.

So the easiest way to add support for Unicode names is to simply set `bit 11` to one. Instead of

```
FileName, _ := Zip.Create(Path)
```

Start your zip entry with:

```
h := &zip.FileHeader{Name:Path, Method: zip.Deflate, Flags: 0x800}
FileName, _ := Zip.CreateHeader(h)
```

The first line creates a `FileHeader` in which `0x800` (`bit 11`) value is set for the `Flags` field which tells that the file name will be encoded using `UTF-8` (which is what Go does when it writes a `string` to an `io.Writer`).

**Note:**

By doing this, UTF-8 filenames will be preserved, but not all zip reader/extractor supports it. For example on Windows, the windows file handler, the Windows Explorer will not decode it as UTF-8, but for example a more serious Zip handler (e.g. [SecureZip](https://www.pkware.com/software/securezip)) will see the UTF-8 file names and will extract the file names properly (using UTF-8 decoding).

Comment: Note: this flag is added automatically since Go 1.10 if you use UTF-8 characters; see the `NonUFT8`  flag in [`zip.FileHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader). Also see the comments in [the source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/04dc1b2/src/archive/zip/writer.go#L266-L289).

Answer (score -2):

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var (
        Path = os.Args[1]
        Name = os.Args[2]
    )

    File, _ := os.Create(Name)
    PS := strings.Split(Path, "\\")
    PathName := strings.Join(PS[:len(PS)-1], "\\")
    os.Chdir(PathName)
    Path = PS[len(PS)-1]
    defer File.Close()
    Zip := zip.NewWriter(File)
    defer Zip.Close()
    walk := func(Path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        Src, _ := os.Open(Path)
        defer Src.Close()
        //FileName, _ := Zip.Create(Path)
        h := &zip.FileHeader{Name: Path, Method: zip.Deflate, Flags: 0x800}
        FileName, _ := Zip.CreateHeader(h)
        io.Copy(FileName, Src)
        Zip.Flush()
        return nil
    }
    if err := filepath.Walk(Path, walk); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add an explanation on how this solves the problem.